# Sight reading trebel and bass clef at same time

Tags: piano, sight-reading, hand-independence

I am very happy to read bass and treble individually. I can also play them individually very well.
I tend to learn a piece(small to medium size and easy to medium with a hard one thrown in now and then)
But when I try to put them together, it's almost back to square one, I can barely do it.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I read/learn a few bars individually then put these few bars together and so on?
Any insight from experienced pianist would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, working on a short section can help.  But most of all, make sure you can play the separate hands slowly WITH NO FUMBLES. Preferably with a metronome click.  Then start putting it together, even more slowly.

Comment: I can do that, no fumble, just following the sheet music. Do I need to combine reading as well as remembering? Metronome work isn't a problem. How do you or did it? What were the stages? What does reading music mean to you?

Comment: To me, reading music means I can earn a living!
Just plod on.  Fluency will come.  Maybe you're at a consolidation stage rather than a leaping ahead one.  This can be frustrating for an adult learner.

Comment: Genius! I am on a very strong consolidation stage with everything I've learnt so far which is most of all the classical stuff there is to know due to lack of time available to me. Deconstructing and reconstructing all scales and chord. I guess it's rubbed off on my sight reading. You hit the nail right on the head!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if your problem is *reading* two staves at the same time, or *playing* independently with both hands.

You can certainly practise the "playing" problem without the complication of sight-reading at the same time. Find some short exercises with different rhythms in each hand that you can memorize.

Learning to do several different things simultaneously takes time and effort. Even a very good piano student can expect to keep facing harder challenges over a time scale of many years - right up to "professional pianist" level.

Comment: I can play independently with two hands, not a problem. Reading 2 staves is the key. What does reading music mean to you? What were the stages you went through?